# Polynomial approximation for small x

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

I found this approximation made in a paper. The equation was essentially,

$H = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\frac{\lambda}{2}((x^2+a^2)^{1/2}-a)^2$

and that for small x this could be approximated as

$H = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\frac{\lambda}{8a^2}x^4$

I can't even begin to understand how they got this. I tried a taylor series but did not get anywhere close to this. This was a peer reviewed paper, any ideas how someone could take logical steps to make this approximation?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x%5E2+%2B+%7Ca%7C%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29+taylor+series

Comment: Where is $i$ in this formula ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} - a = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} + a} \sim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{2a},$$
where $f(x) \sim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ is shorthand for $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks so much!